# Why not Answering Questions from Homeworks?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, asking-questions

I am really **not** trying to be funny or polemic, but I don't seem to understand why people are bothered with questions that are from users' homework.

Fair enough that we would like to encourage people to learn on their own, as this will make them learn a lot more, rather than simply giving them the answers; but put it this way: the fact that they are going to the trouble of asking the question is not an indication to wanting to find it out? It can perhaps be a very lazy approach, but nonetheless it is still better than people who do not bother doing their homework in first place. Also some of those questions, even though are from homework, are really good, so a lot more people would also benefit humongously from the answers provided. Plus, who really cares if that student is learning to his/her full potential? It's his/her time and money spent, but I, on another hand, just like many others who are really interested in learning as much as possible, will definitely look at the questions/answer and say: "actually that is very good!".

I can see that people may retort, saying that it is not fair to the  university/college/colleagues. I would pose the question: "why not?" If the resource is available online and the student managed to find it, it is already something.

When I seem to disagree with what appears to be the majority's opinion, my first thought is that I am wrong and so I seek to find strong counter-arguments to make me change my mind. So I am just trying to figure out what the general rationale behind this topic is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem isn't with homework or homework-related questions per se. The problem is with *how* most homework questions are asked. Most homework questions tend to misrepresent the issue at hand because they're about previously taught cases. That makes it difficult to correctly answer the question and usually brings a long discussion by the OP under the answers.

I'm pretty sure that some of the best questions here are homework or homework-related, but only a fraction of the questions here get called out as homework questions. Do you know why? It's simply, it's because of their low quality.

It has nothing to do with universities, students, or the education system. Homework questions aren't banned or disallowed here. On the contrary, any good questions that benefit the questioner and future visitors are more than welcome.

I'm sure that most of us here share this opinion.

Comment: Well put. Though I think an even bigger part is how the questions are phrased: often it is simply a copy/paste of the professor's question, direct from the homework. Again, it is about the quality of question, and a good question that happens to be sourced from homework could be fine. However a no-effort, "giv me teh codez"-equivalent, do-my-homework-for-me type question, that is what gets called out.

Comment: So I guess we all have a very similar view, as I agree with all conditions. Thanks for sharing, @Adnan/AviD♦