# Do we do meta tags like [homework]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently the tag [homework](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) was introduced on [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143934/backdoor-account-in-passwd-file), with the following usage guidance:

> A question identified as a homework assignment.

This sounds very much like a meta tag to me - it is more about the motivation for asking the question, than about the actual tag itself. On SO there has long been a concensus that [meta tags should not be used](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Does that apply here as well?

Normally I would just kill a tag with only one question, but since this one seems to have been deliberatly created I figured it should be discussed here first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely agree, it is pointless and not a good path to go down. I think it was added out of anger, towards an apparently deceitful OP who was trying to "put one over on us". Understandable, but still not something we would want to condone, and allow to be misused. Removed.

Answer (score 4):

Sometime in the history of our site, we decided to remove the homework tag, which is why you don't find the tag anywhere. I haven't been able to find that history in searching meta, but [here's something of a reference](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/why-not-answering-questions-from-homeworks/1362#1362).